# find homography matrix using openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

i'm working on a project of image stitching using OpenCV 2.3.1 on Visual Studio 2012.
For an unknown reason my programme don't work !!

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

       using namespace cv;
       using namespace std;
Mat getHomography() 
{

    vector<Point2f> points1;
    vector<Point2f> points2;

    points1.push_back(Point2f(10, 100));
    points1.push_back(Point2f(100, 10));
    points1.push_back(Point2f(200, 20));
    points1.push_back(Point2f(80, 30));

    points2.push_back(Point2f(220, 20));
    points2.push_back(Point2f(10, 220));
    points2.push_back(Point2f(90, 120));
    points2.push_back(Point2f(100, 20));

    Mat H = findHomography(Mat(points1), Mat(points2), 8, 3.0); 
    return H;
}

int main(){


    Mat HH = getHomography();
    cout<<HH;
    system("pause");

        return 0; 
}
```

my problem : 
[image]
any help plzzz

Answer (score 2):

you need at least 4 points in each vec. 2 just aren't enough

Comment: "getHompgraphy",  hehe, i like it, sounds nice :)

Comment: could you tell me plz how to display this matrix H ?

Comment: oh, sorry, `std::cout << H << std::endl;`

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>`   for system().    and if i use `cout<<H<<endl;` i get a matrix like `[-0.8181818181818187, -0.8181818181818414, 90.00000000000036;
  -1.090909090909092, -1.090909090909091, 119.9999999999999;
  -0.009090909090909094, -0.009090909090909177, 1]`

Comment: 0x00000005 means, you've got the wrong libs/dlls check for 32bit exe 64bit dlls or the other way, also don't use debug libs in release mode or the other way

Comment: i use vs2012 && OpenCV2.2 really i don't know what to do now :(

Comment: check the opencv libs you linked. for debug, there should be a "d" at the end, for release not. if you compile 32 bit, use the libs in opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib, for 64 bit opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib . and point your PATH to opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin  ( or x64 )

Comment: for Debug --> opencv_calib3d220.lib
opencv_calib3d220d.lib
opencv_contrib220.lib
opencv_contrib220d.lib
opencv_core220.lib
opencv_core220d.lib
opencv_features2d220.lib
opencv_features2d220d.lib
opencv_ffmpeg220.lib
opencv_ffmpeg220d.lib
opencv_flann220.lib
opencv_flann220d.lib
opencv_gpu220.lib
opencv_gpu220d.lib
opencv_highgui220.lib
opencv_highgui220d.lib
opencv_imgproc220.lib
opencv_imgproc220d.lib
opencv_legacy220.lib
opencv_legacy220d.lib
opencv_ml220.lib
opencv_ml220d.lib
opencv_objdetect220.lib
opencv_objdetect220d.lib
opencv_ts220.lib
opencv_video220.lib
opencv_video220d.lib

Comment: in my path i have : C:\OpenCV2.2\lib

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by changing from vs2012 to vs 2010 :D